# Unable to debug Threads on Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0)

Tags: android, multithreading, debugging, samsung-mobile

Since I have updated Galaxy S5 to Lollipop I'm unable to debug only part
of the code that is run in the background.
In cases i put breakpoint somewhere on UI code, execution will normally
halt there. Prior to update debugging threads was possible.

What I have tried:

- used different cables
- tested on different computer
- tested with Android studio and Eclipse
- tested on Linux and Windows
- manually waited for debugger to attach
- restarted device
- wrote small test application that does something with thread

I can't seem to find anyone with similar problem, so this really puzzles
me. In the end i guess it is possible bug was introduced with official
update, but maybe I'm missing something.

Anyone had similar problems with possible solution? Maybe with different
devices.

EDIT:
If i suspend thread manually i can step out of sleep to see every line of
execution with thread states, so debugging should be possible. 
Still, every breakpoint is ignored if I continue execution.